# How to return sequelize findAll(array) in the original order of the array?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table that represents a list which can be reordered on the front end. I also have a table which stores the items in that list. So the ordering info is kept separate from the actual items. When I reorder a list say:

```
id   item    order
------------------
1    item-1    1
2    item-2    2
3    item-3    3
```

to

```
id   item    order
------------------
1    item-1    3
2    item-2    1
3    item-3    2
```

you can see the order column no longer lines up with the id column. In order to ensure consistent object building I have a generic function which takes in an array of ids and preforms a `findAll()` query on the table that holds the actual items, not their order. The problem I'm having is that the `findAll()` query seems to default the `orderby` clause to be based on the ids it's passed, when what I want is for the array of models to be returned in the same order as the array of ids was fed into it.

While I could do a `findOne()` in the sequential order of the ids, that seems like an inefficient way to do this.

The actual function is question is this:

```
async buildQuestion(question){
    // check if question is array to allow for faster querying of multiple questions
    if(Array.isArray(question)){
      const ids = question.filter(item => item.id).map(item => item.id);
      const questions = db.questions.findAll({
        where: { id: ids },
        include: [db.formats, db.categories, db.types, db.questionHints, db.questionVideos]
      });

      return questions.map(question => new Promise(resolve => _build(question).then(item => resolve(item))));
    }else{
      if (!question.id) throw new Error('question.id required at Builder.buildQuestion()');
      question = await db.questions.findOne({
        where: { id: question.id },
        include: [db.formats, db.categories, db.types, db.questionHints, db.questionVideos]
      });

      return _build(question);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the **only** way to order a SQL result set is with the `order by` clause, so you would have to add the current order to the database table to accomplish your goal.

If this isn't possible, you could write js code to add the current order value to the result set, then sort.  This would likely more efficient than multiple queries, particularly if the result set is large.

Here's some sample code that works... though it may not be the cleanest code :)

```
let myOrder = [3, 1, 2];

User.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'username',
        [Sequelize.literal("0"), 'myOrder']   /* to hold desired order */
    ],            
    where : {id : myOrder}
})
.then(users => {

    /* add desired sequence to result set */
    for (let ord = 0; ord < myOrder.length; ord++) {
        let usr = users.find(user => user.id == myOrder[ord]);
        if (usr) {
            usr.dataValues.myOrder = ord;
        }            
    }

    /* sort in desired order */
    users.sort((a, b) => a.dataValues.myOrder - b.dataValues.myOrder);

    res.send(users);
    next();
});
```